# Combining point feature classes with identical locations in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, feature-class

I have 3 point feature classes made from rasters that have identical locations and "pointid". I want a single feature class that 1 point for each location but contains the "gridcode" of each of the 3 points in the attribute table. Posted below is the relevant code.

```
    raster_list = [rasterx, rastery, rasterz]
    points_list = []

    for raster in raster_list:
        points_grid = arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(raster,f"{raster}_points","Value")
        arcpy.AlterField_management(points_grid,"grid_code",f"{raster}_value")
        points_list.append(points_grid)
```

My first idea was spatial join, but I'm not sure how to implement it in a loop, and I want it to be adaptable to a tool. but couldn't come up with an expression that worked. Is there a geoprocessing tool or code snippet that can easily combine these into a single point feature class?

---

I figured out a way to do it very slowly using two cursors and iterating through the points. Took me about 17 minutes to get through 8,000  points.

```
copy = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(points_list[0],"copy")
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(copy,"grid_code")

    analysis_table = arcpy.CreateTable_management(gdb,"analysis_table")

    arcpy.CopyRows_management(copy, analysis_table)

    for item in str_raster_list:
        arcpy.AddField_management(analysis_table,item,"FLOAT")

    str_raster_list.insert(0,"pointid")

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(analysis_table,str_raster_list) as give_val:
        for row in give_val:
            new_vals = []
            for points in points_list:
                with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points,["pointid","grid_code"]) as find_val:
                    for item in find_val:
                        if item[0] == row[0]:
                            new_vals.append(item[1])
            new_vals.insert(0,row[0])
            give_val.updateRow(new_vals)
```

I don't know if there's a faster way to do it but it gets the data to parse exactly how I need it to.

Comment: If all the tables have the same points, you only need one table. Otherwise you can use theme-on-theme selection, then flip the selection set and Append. This is not likely to be an existing tool, but could be made into one in a score of lines of code.

Comment: Spatial join b to a and c to first result. Perhaps change field names in b and c before it.

Comment: Do you have access to spatial analyst extension? If so Combine https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Combine/009z0000007r000000/ would save you a lot of work.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Problem is that raster to poly only lets me use one value, so I'm still back to square one.

Comment: Extract multivalues to points will take about 30 seconds for that no of points.

Comment: To export polygons the field is 'value' which can then be joined to the raster attribute table... but the question was about points. As for your updated code try to avoid cursor in cursor operations, as you've noticed they're slow, digest all the values into a dictionary from a search cursor then access the dictionary values whilst in the update cursor - there are many examples on this site about this concept.